# Is there a shortcut to reuse the last operator+motion without repeating the whole change?

Tags: cursor-motions

Many times I find my self running `ciw` or `c2W` but with different text. Like `ciwnewtext<esc>` and then `ciwanothertext<esc>`. The dot command `.` will repeat the whole change (it does not allow me to specify the text).

For simple motions like `iw` it does not bother my much but sometimes I use more complex motion that I would like to reuse right away. Is there any way to accomplish that?

Comment: Could you provide examples on what you call 'more complex motion' and what would the 'magic command' do?

Comment: motions like `3fJ` or `\longword`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you movement involves searches on the current line ([`:help f`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#f) or [`:help t`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#t)) you could repeat that movements with [`;`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%3b) and [`,`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%2c):

```
cfxnewtext
c;anothertext
```

For regular searches you could use [`n`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#n):

```
c/xyz<enter>newtext
cnanothertext
```

If you are using a combination of searches and movements, like search for `pattern1` and then jump some sentences/words, you could record a macro:

```
qq<complex movements>c2w<c-o>q
```

The [`i_CTRL-O`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL%2dO) allows you to finish the macro while in insert mode. Then you can play the macro using `@q` (or [`@@`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#%40%40)) and you will end in insert mode with the old text already removed.